# Unable to Render jsp page

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I'm manually creating webapp/WEB-INF/views folder inside the src/main and also adding the 2 dependency like org.apache.tomcat.embed and javax.servlet but still it throws `404` When I'm calling URL of Controller

**Controller.**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HolidayController {

    @GetMapping("/test11")
    public String getData()
    {

        System.out.println("in the test contoller");
        return "demoJsp";
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot config file.**

```
package com.chml.Chml_Admin;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.chml")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.chml")
@ComponentScan("com.chml")
public class ChmlAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChmlAdminApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.properties.**

```
#==== connect to mysql ======# 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chml_admin 
spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password= 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 

#==== Internal View Resolver ======# 

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**JSP.**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Demo</title>
 </head>
   <body>
     <h3>This is jsp content</h3>
   </body>
  </html>
```

**pom.xml.**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

> Here I Added My project structure

[image]

I tried various things but i did not get any Solution of this ,
Please tell me if I'm going wrong Anywhere.

Comment: add your project structure screenshot

Comment: @lucumt i have Just Added my project structure screenshot

Comment: i'm still not got any proper answer which can resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot ,you need to change the view prefix from `views` to `jsps` in **application.properties.**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: @vishals. then add the full code of your controller and spring configuration file,so that others can check if it config correctly,such as the package scan